# Creating a custom Serial Number in Primary Key in mvc4

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a website in mvc4 and i want to ask that as i am registering a new user than the user-profile table automatically updated with user-id as auto increment in the `1,2,3,4,5,...`sequence but i want this primary key to auto-increment in some other way such as `psk1,psk2,psk3.................`..can i have this ?? if Yes how it is possible?

I have try using custom membership provider but i am not successful by using that method so can any one have better option other than this?

Comment: If your custom serial numbers are going to be sequential anyway (prefix + number), why not just use a regular auto-increment id as you have, then calculate the serial number from that whenever you need it?

Comment: @BrianRogers have used prefix and value is submitted but now the problem is that i am not able to insert  new value as it is not adding +1 one to the last element ..how can i do this ..how can i get the primary key value in linq?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three ways of creating unique primary keys

- Autoincrement by **identity**.

This is the method that you are already familiar with, leading to automatic generation of primary keys of type 1,2,3,....

- Using **UUID**.

This is a global unique identified which you can create in .NET and pass it as value in your database record.

- **Custom creation** of primary key

If there is a special need, you could set your data table column to be primary Key of type `varchar` and create either in the .NET domain, or in the SQL server using a [trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx). There, you could find the last inserted ID, parse it, increment the integer part and form the new unique primary key. .

Hope I helped!

Comment: i have used this now    [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] but now problem is it is not adding +1 after each id